# How can I dump the elements of a list into the global enviornment (or equivalently a function's enviornment)?

Tags: r, scope

I've got a list that I have saved.  I want to load the list, and then have all of its elements transferred to the global environment.  Or, equivalently, to a function's environment if the object is loaded inside a function.

Here is a simple example.  How can I automate the last few lines?

```
L <- list(goats = 'goats', cheese = 'cheese'
, numbarz = 1:5, nice.model = lm(rnorm(100)~rexp(100)))
save(L, 'L.Rda')
rm(L)
load('L.Rda')
goats <- L$goats
cheese <- L$cheese
numbarz <- L$numbarz
nice.model <- L$nice.model
```

Comment: See `?list2env`.

Comment: Yeah `list2env` sounds like what you want. But as always in these cases I have to ask why do you want to do this?

Comment: `list2env(L, .GlobalEnv)` !!  Want some points?  Make it an answer

Comment: @Dason I'm working on a paper where some bootstrapping routines take a long time.  I want to save the results when done, then comment-out the lines that run them and then load them later.  It is much less cluttery if I save the results as a list.

Comment: It's not like this is production code or anything